# how to orderby on timespan field in c#?

Tags: c#

Im using C#. I have a list of events:

```
List<Event> events = new List<Event>();
```

and each event has a name and time. So if you were to look in the list you would see something like so:

```
Event A | 18:00
Event B | 18:30
Event C | 18:45
Event D | 18:15
```

I have been trying to make the list ordered by the time of the event but it doesn't seem to have worked. I used this in my controller:

```
events.OrderBy(e => e.Time);
```

After looking online, I saw that some people user OrderBy and ThenBy, so I tried:

```
events.OrderBy(e => e.Time.ToString().Length).ThenBy(e => e.Time);
```

but this didn't work either. Can anyone help? Thanks

Comment: What type of your Time property? Or could you provide the class `Event`?

Comment: Time is using TimeSpan

Comment: Event is just simply made up of a name which is string and Time which is TimeSpan

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`OrderBy` and `ThenBy` does not sort `List` in place - it creates new collection with the same items sorted.

You have to reassign your list with ordered one:

```
events = events.OrderBy(e => e.Time).ToList();
```

or with `ThenBy`:

```
events = events.OrderBy(e => e.Time.).ThenBy(e => e.AsrTime).ToList();
```

Answer (score 3):

If you're *just* calling [`OrderBy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/bb534966.aspx) as a separate statement, that definitely won't work. Like all LINQ methods, `OrderBy` doesn't mutate the original sequence - instead it returns a *new* sequence with the ordering applied.

So you want something like:

```
var orderedEvents = events.OrderBy(e => e.Time);
```

or for a compound ordering:

```
var orderedEvents = events.OrderBy(e => e.Time).ThenBy(e => e.AsrTime);
```

I would strongly advise you *not* to call `e.Time.ToString()`, and certainly not to order by the *length* of the string. Fundamentally you're not interested in the string representation, so don't bother using it.

You can call `ToList()` on the result if you need to, but if you're just going to iterate over it once, there's little point in materializing the result. If you're going to iterate over it multiple times, calling `ToList` will make sure the ordering only needs to happen once, instead of every time it's iterated over.

It's really important to understand the functional nature of LINQ, and the way it composes operations by making each one return a new sequence which is the result of applying an operation to the previous sequence - usually lazily.